# MySQL query in spring-security.xml for authorization

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Q1. > How do I check whether the following two queries is executed or not in spring-security.xml ?

```
 <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
          users-by-username-query=
            "select user_login_name as username,user_password as password,user_type_id,role_id from sox_audit.sox_users where user_login_name=? and user_password=?"

           authorities-by-username-query=
            "select user_login_name as username,role_id as authority from sox_audit.sox_users where user_login_name ='sriram@gmail.com' and user_password='12345' "/>
```

I can able to login with hardcoded values and give authorities as per the user type. But I cannot By selecting the records from DB.

Can anyone help me out in this.

Comment: Your queries are wrong, plain wrong. The users-by-username one should return 3 values, username,password and enabled nothing more, nothing less. It should also query only on username not password (i.e. just a single parameter). Your authorities by username has the same flaw it should only have a username as the parameter not password. So basically your queries are wrong. See [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-jdbc-user-service-attributes) on what to return and what is used to query on.

Answer (score 1):

Enable logs for `JdbcDaoImpl` which implements `UserDetailsService`.
something like:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl=DEBUG
```

If that doesn't work, add some breakpoints on this class and debug it on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. 
Thing is query is wrong. 
users-by-username-query will take only 3 parameters. It should be username, password and enabled from database.
Also, 
authorities-by-username-query will take 2 parameters.

```
 users-by-username-query=
            "select user_login_name as username,user_password as password,enabled from sox_audit.sox_users where user_login_name=?"

           authorities-by-username-query=
            "select user_login_name as username,authority from sox_audit.sox_users where user_login_name =?"/>
```

Then control the users in HomeController. This will work perfectly.